# Time reversal operation on Holstein-Primakoff bosons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, many-body, time-reversal-symmetry

My starting point is to find out how the time reversal operator $\Theta$ acts on Holstein-Primakoff (HP) bosons ($\hat{a}_i$ and $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i$).

Since the HP bosons are related to spin operators through Holstein-Primakoff transformation
\begin{aligned}
\hat{S}_{i}^{z} &= S-\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\hat{a}_i,\\
\hat{S}_{i}^{+} &= \sqrt{2S-\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\hat{a}_i}\hat{a}_i,\\
\hat{S}_{i}^{-} &= \hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\sqrt{2S-\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\hat{a}_i},
\end{aligned}
the action on HP bosons is determined by the action on spin operators
\begin{equation}
\Theta\hat{S}_{i}^{+}\Theta^{-1} = -\hat{S}_{i}^{-}.
\end{equation}
When the high-order terms are ignored, the HP relations become $\hat{S}_{i}^{+}=\sqrt{2S}\hat{a}_i$ and $\hat{S}_{i}^{-}=\sqrt{2S}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i$, hence leading to $\Theta\hat{a}_i=-\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i$ and $\Theta\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i=-\hat{a}_i$. I expected to obtain the same result when the high-order terms are preserved. However, it turns out wrong because
\begin{aligned}
\Theta\hat{S}_{i}^{+}\Theta^{-1} &= \sqrt{2S-\left(\Theta\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\Theta^{-1}\right)\left(\Theta\hat{a}_i\Theta^{-1}\right)}\left(\Theta\hat{a}_i\Theta^{-1}\right),\\
-\hat{S}_{i}^{-} &= -\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\sqrt{2S-\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\hat{a}_i}=-\sqrt{2S+1-\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\hat{a}_i}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i,
\end{aligned}
where the last equation utilizes the identity (Eq.63 in  https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.07122)
\begin{equation}
\left(\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\right)^k\sqrt{2S-\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\hat{a}_i}=\sqrt{2S+k-\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\hat{a}_i}\left(\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\right)^k.
\end{equation}
It is straightforward to find that $\Theta\hat{a}_i=-\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i$ and $\Theta\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i=-\hat{a}_i$ results in
\begin{equation}
\Theta\hat{S}_{i}^{+}\Theta^{-1} = \sqrt{2S-\hat{a}_i\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i}\left(-\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\right) = -\sqrt{2S-1-\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\hat{a}_i}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\neq -\hat{S}_{i}^{-}.
\end{equation}
In other words, HP bosons transform differently under time reversal operation when the high-order terms are ignored and preserved.

My question is then: Why could this difference happen? Is there any interpretation from the physical perspective?

Comment: @ Cosmas Zachos This is indeed a subtle point, because one can not obtain the bosonic commutation relation under the first order approximation $\hat{S}^{+}_{i}=\sqrt{2S}\hat{a}_{i}$ and $\hat{S}^{-}_{i}=\sqrt{2S}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i}$ (I'm confused about it). On the other hand, the isomorphism you've mentioned, in spite of preserving commutation relation, will lead to $\Theta\hat{S}^{+}_{i}\Theta^{-1}=\sqrt{2S}\Theta\hat{a}_{i}\Theta^{-1}=\sqrt{2S}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i}\neq-\hat{S}^{-}_{i}$ which is contradict with the fact that time reversal transforms $\hat{S}_{i}$ to $-\hat{S}_{i}$.

Comment: You need to specify in your question that, by "time reversal", you *mean*  mapping to the *conjugate representation*, as you now specified, for hermitian $\hat S_i$ s... And seek such a conjugate rep for the oscillator algebra.